# Upload file using Jquery/Ajax to local REST service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I want to upload files to our DB through my REST service using the file explorer, as of now I manage to open the file explorer by clicking my `findDocumentOnboarding` button of `input type="file"`. But I have not managed to upload the selected file using my `uploadDocumentOnboarding` button.

I have tried using the following code:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" value="Upload document" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary uploadDocumentOnboarding">
<input id="file" type="file" class="findDocumentOnboarding">
```

**Jquery/Javascript**:

```
    $(".uploadDocumentOnboarding").on(click, function (evt) {
    IdToEdit = $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('p.important').text();
    alert(IdToEdit);
    var url = "http://localhost:10110/MavenProject/api123/Onboard/uploads/"+IdToEdit;
    evt.preventDefault();

    var documentData = new FormData();
    documentData.append("file", $('input#file.findDocumentOnboarding')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: {'testBlob': (documentData)},
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: I'm now getting `PUT 415 Unsupported Media Type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it like this, notice the POST instead of PUT and the data and appended data difference:

```
    $(".uploadDocumentOnboarding").on("click", function (evt) {
    IdToEdit = $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('p.important').text();
    var url = "http://localhost:10110/MavenProject/api123/Onboard/uploads/"+IdToEdit;
    evt.preventDefault();

    var documentData = new FormData();
    documentData.append('file', $('input#file.findDocumentOnboarding')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: documentData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Document uploaded successfully.");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `.on("click"` for `.on(click` ; removing `async: false,` , `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',`

Comment: Same problem, nothing happends when I'm pressing the Upload Document button.